# Problem of not being able to import gym_unity, stable_baseline3, and mlagents_envs in Google Colab

Tags: python

I am studying about mlagents. As stated in the title, the gym_unity, stable_baseline3, and mlagents_envs modules do not run. Of course, it's probably because it wasn't installed properly, so please tell me how to solve it.

[This error occurs when importing a module.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSOue.png)
This error occurs when importing a module.

[This is an error that occurs specifically when installing gym_unity, and it puzzles me a bit.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwNn8.png)
This is an error that occurs specifically when installing gym_unity, and it puzzles me a bit.

I tried various searches and tried running it, but the error was not resolved. If there is a solution, please let me know.

Comment: Please post the code and error as text, and a screenshot.

Comment: Screenshots cannot be attached directly due to lack of reputation. I made a new post, if you know a solution please help! It is about install and import gym_unity in Google Colab.